# Is there a valid purpose behind parametered function calls that are set within event listeners?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

In the snippet below, I have 3 buttons with 3 event listeners linked to them:

**1)** The first button has a click event that calls the function *doSomething*, and does not send any parameters.

**2)** The second button has a click event that calls an anonymous function, and the anonymous function calls the function *doSomethingElse*, but sends a parameter along with it.

**3)** The third button has a click event that calls the function *doAnotherSomethingElse*, and also sends a parameter with it.

Now the first 2 examples, I believe, are the correct ways to call functions from event listeners: The first without a parameter, and the second when sending a parameter. The third example, I think, is **not** a correct way to call a function, and indeed, the listener does not work. In this example, the function is called, but it is called only when the event code is executed on page load. The event listener is not created, and therefore, clicking the button produces no result.

While I understand that example 3 is not the correct way to call a function with parameters from an event listener, I don't understand **why I then don't get any errors in the console?** I also don't understand **why the function is actually  successfully called (once) and the parameter is successfully passed?** It almost seems as though the code is valid and correct, and it does have a purpose, but I'm not using it for the correct purpose, because I don't understand what it is for.

Is there a valid purpose behind parametered function calls that are set within event listeners? Is it a bug that no errors are produced for the code? Or are there any scenarios where this is legitimately used for some purpose?

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
var res1 = document.getElementById("result1");
var res2 = document.getElementById("result2");
var res3 = document.getElementById("result3");

function doSomething() {
  res1.innerHTML = res1.innerHTML + "Function doSomething called<br/>";
}

function doSomethingElse(parm) {
  res2.innerHTML = res2.innerHTML + "Function doSomethingElse called with parameter " + parm + "<br/>";
}

function doAnotherSomethingElse(parm) {
  res3.innerHTML = res3.innerHTML + "Function doAnotherSomethingElse called with parameter " + parm + "<br/>";
}

function start() {
  btn1.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);
  //
  btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    doSomethingElse("foo");
  }, false);
  //
  btn3.addEventListener("click", doAnotherSomethingElse("bar"), false);
}

window.load = start();
```

```css
button,
div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#btn1, #result1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#btn2, #result2 {
  background-color: coral;
}

#btn3, #result3 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button> <button id="btn2">Button 2</button> <button id="btn3">Button 3</button>

<div id="result1">
</div>

<div id="result2">
</div>

<div id="result3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible purpose is if you have a function which *returns* another function, sometimes called currying:

```js
const makeFn = param => () => console.log('invoking fn with param', param);
button.addEventListener('click', makeFn('foo'));
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Or, if you don't like using arrow functions (which can have implicit return):

```js
const makeFn = function(param) {
  return function() {
    console.log('invoking fn with param', param);
  };
};
button.addEventListener('click', makeFn('foo'));
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

In this case, invoking `makeFn` at the time you add the listener can be perfectly fine.

> I don't understand why I then don't get any errors in the console?

Because, unfortunately, `addEventListener` does not *require* that the parameter it gets passed is a function. Instead, it will just silently fail.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', null);
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

> I also don't understand why the function is actually successfully called (once) and the parameter is successfully passed?

Because `()` after a function name will invoke the function. So

```
btn3.addEventListener("click", doAnotherSomethingElse("bar"), false);
```

will call `doAnotherSomethingElse` with the parameter `bar`, changing `res3.innerHTML`, but because `doAnotherSomethingElse` doesn't return a function, no event listener will be set.

One way to mitigate these sorts of problems is to use a type-checker, which will warn you while you're writing the code if you don't pass the expected arguments.

Also note that, in your snippet,

```
window.load = start();
```

results in the same problem you're describing. You're calling `start` immediately, when the above line is run, rather than telling the browser to run `start` when the window is loaded. The proper way to do this would be

```
window.onload = start;
```

(without invoking `start`), just like you would do when attaching a listener with a named function:

```js
const fn = () => console.log('fn invoked');
const fn2 = () => console.log('fn 2 invoked');

document.addEventListener('click', fn);
document.onclick = fn2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when calling a function while providing an argument, the return value of that function becomes the argument instead.

> why the function is actually successfully called (once) and the parameter is successfully passed?

Because this is exactly how javascript works. It's kinda like calling a function to create new arguments as shown below:

```
function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }
function multiply(a, b) { return a * b; }

multiply(
    3,
    sum(2,3) //returns 5
) //3 * 5 returns 15
```

So in this context:

```
btn3.addEventListener("click", doAnotherSomethingElse("bar"), false);
```

`doAnotherSomethingElse('bar')` is called during the creation of the listener, but since it doesn't return anything. `.addEventListener(evtname, callback, someBool)` is called with arguments `'click'`, `undefined` and `false`;

`.addEventListener()` might contain a flag for the callback parameter to not execute (or execute with an empty function instead) when the callback isn't a function, so there was no error being logged, something similar to:

```
function addEventListener(evtname, callback, someBool){
   if(callback) callback();
   //or
   callback = callback || function(){};
   callback();

   //...
}
```

All in all, everything is perfectly valid

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!